# TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined - karma Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I try to test angular service and this is my code

```
angular.module('testApp', []).factory('Person', function () {
    return function Person (name) {
        this.name = name;
    };
});
```

Test case :

```
describe('Person', function () {

    var Person;
    beforeEach(module('testApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_Person_) {
        Person = _Person_;
    }));

    describe('Constructor', function () {

        it('assigns a name', function () {
            expect(new Person('Ben')).to.have.property('name', 'Ben');
        });
    });
});
```

I get this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined at Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to.have.property` is a [Chai](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) assertion

I haven't use this but there is a library to [add the toHaveProperty matcher to Jasmine](https://github.com/hyzhak/to-have-property).

Otherwise you could use this with Jasmine:

```
expect((new Person('Ben')).name).toEqual('Ben');
```